# Generate a random number with pre-defined length PHP

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm trying to create a function using mt_rand() in order to generate a truly random number, since rand() just isn't suffice.

The problem is I need to pre-define the length of the number, say I need a 10 digit random number.

Anyway, I've been messing around and this is what I've come up with:

```
    function randomNumber($length) {
        $min = str_repeat(0, $length-1) . 1;
        $max = str_repeat(9, $length);
        return mt_rand($min, $max);   
    }
```

In theory that should work (as far as I can tell), but it doesn't. The length is completely random and it also throws out negative values.

Any ideas?

Comment: "in order to generate a truly random number" Well, you'll still get a pseudo-random number. Even the Mersenne twister can't get you a truly random number. The closest you might get is from http://www.random.org/ with their atmospheric noise data.

Comment: Regardless, that's not the issue, mt_rand() is a lot more random than rand().

Comment: rand(min,max) will return an integer, so only within the range of PHP 32-bit integers on a 32-bit system.... also remember that 0000000001 == 1, so your range is 1 to 9999999999, you want $min = 1 . str_repeat(0, $length-1)

Comment: Also, with random.org, I don't want to have to curl their website each time.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the length. It's still generating 8 digit strings, and it's still generating negative values.

Comment: @Karl.... I'll repeat: "rand(min,max) will return an integer, so only within the range of PHP 32-bit integers on a 32-bit system"

Comment: mt_rand() only generates random numbers less than the value mt_getrandmax() returns. It is said to always be 2^31 - 1, even on 64-Bit-Systems. This effectively makes it impossible to generate arbitrary length strings with your function, the maximum length might be 9 characters.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If by “a truly random number” you mean a cryptographically secure random number, make sure to use [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) instead of `mt_rand`. `mt_rand` is not based on a CSPRNG. **If you don’t know whether you need a CSPRNG, use `random_int` anyway** – it’s not slow.

If you want an n-digit numeric string, that's exactly what you should get: n individual digits.

```
function random_digits($length) {
    $result = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= random_int(0, 9);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The reason your existing code isn't working is because `0000...01` is still `1` to `mt_rand`, and also that `mt_rand`'s range isn't infinite. The negative numbers are integer overflows.

Comment: Valid point, however, I've just tried that and it's still not sticking to the length for some reason, it's generated a string 12 digits long.

Comment: @Karl: Yep, sorry, I made a mistake. `mt_rand` is inclusive. Just change the `10` to `9`.

Comment: This can still generate numbers less than ten digits if the first (and second, and third...) is/are 0.

Comment: btw - I can get a random number without a quantum-static thingy - I just have to observe nature and quantify it - we are all in a state of quantum change - for instance, I can capture radioactive decay quite easily with a digital camera and a piece of Americanum (from a smoke detector).  Randomness is not hard, its just hard inside the machine.

Comment: Actually Tom, it doesn't, I've just generated a few and each time it's been the correct length (even times it's started with a 0).

Comment: @TomSmilack: [Nope!](http://codepad.org/cdnJrYCD) Darn weak typing again, huh? :D

Comment: Oh, I assumed these would be used as numbers rather than left as strings.

Comment: Why not just mt_rand(100000000, 999999999) ?

Comment: @MyWetSocks: No leading zeroes, and for a generic function that you can pass a length to, it (a) doesn’t save much and (b) doesn’t work for 10 or more digits (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php).

Answer (score 10):

just sepcify the range to rand method , if you need 4 digit random number then just use it as

```
rand(1000,9999);
```

Answer (score 8):

Short and sweet:

I'm assuming only legitimate numbers, not strings like 00010.  Try useing the size of your number to be:

```
  $min = pow(10, $length - 1) ;
  $max = pow(10, $length) - 1;
  return mt_rand($min, $max);
```

The only one that doesn't work is when length is 1, a single digit number '0' won't be a possible value to be returned.

Comment: I think you probably meant to do "ten to the power of length", not "length times ten".

Comment: @minitech yes, I hit submit before I finished editing and running in codepad.org

Comment: mt_rand() does not support arbitrary length random numbers.

Comment: @Sven Do you mean the solution provided will not work in some case? I think it will work because the $min and $max variables will contain the minimum and maximum numbers of length $length respectively. So, the function mt_rand() will have only one length, as option, for its output.

Comment: `mt_rand()` does not output arbitrary numbers. It is limited to not create integers greater than `mt_getrandmax()`, no matter what min and max values you provide. This makes this answer fail for most of the values for `$length` you can provide, except for values between 1 and about 7 or 8. See my comment to the question itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169025/generate-a-random-number-with-pre-defined-length-php/13169102?noredirect=1#comment17920114_13169025.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I'm using:

```
function random_number($length)
{
    return join('', array_map(function($value) { return $value == 1 ? mt_rand(1, 9) : mt_rand(0, 9); }, range(1, $length)));
}
```

One line, nice and simple! The number will never start with 0 and allows 0 at any other place.

Answer (score 2):

```php
function randomNDigitNumber($digits)
{
  $returnString = mt_rand(1, 9);
  while (strlen($returnString) < $digits) {
    $returnString .= mt_rand(0, 9);
  }
  return $returnString;
}
```

> The first line ensures that no "0" precedes any number, for instance values like 012, 0598... will be discarded, the rest is easy

Answer (score 1):

```
function randomNumber($length) {
    $min = 1 . str_repeat(0, $length-1);
    $max = str_repeat(9, $length);
    return mt_rand($min, $max);   
}
```

you have your concat 1 in the wrong spot, your range is this for $length=2: {01,99} - sometimes its 01-09, that is represented as 1-9 not 01-09.  Just start from 10: {10,99} will be your range.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mt_rand(): Argument #1 ($min) must be of type int, string given in /workspace/Main.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /workspace/Main.php(7): mt_rand()
#1 /workspace/Main.php(10): randomNumber()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /workspace/Main.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

Use this for strings of a certain length with both letters and numbers. Tested.

```
protected function randomToken($length = 4, $result='') {

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        $case = mt_rand(0, 1);
        switch($case){

            case 0:
                $data = mt_rand(0, 9);
                break;
            case 1:
                $alpha = range('a','z');
                $item = mt_rand(0, 25);

                $data = strtoupper($alpha[$item]);
                break;
        }

        $result .= $data;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I think you can just use this code instead:
    return substr(uniqid(), 0, $length);

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't start with the length constraining the random numbers. Rather accumulate a long enough output, then cut it to the right length:

```
while (strlen($value) < $length) {
    $value .= str_pad(mt_rand(00000, 99999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
// as pairs of five were added before, eventually remove some again
return substr($value, 0, $length);
```

The padding should be there, because even zeros are randomly generated and should be retained.

Comment: if your random number generator is not good, this could be problematic as you are reducing your world and numbers can repeat in the groups - all depends on implementation. (same can be said about the generator in the first place).  But I would avoid this.

Comment: mt_rand() accepts two integer values. It really does not matter whether you write the zero as "0" or "00000", but the latter is octal number format!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a small range and don't want to generate the same number twice, how about this:

```
function random(int $len): int
{
    static $track = [];
    
    $min = 1 . str_repeat(0, $len - 1);
    $max = str_repeat(9, $len);
    $num = mt_rand($min, $max);
    
    // if was generated before, try again
    if (in_array($num, $track))
    {
        return random($len);
    }
    
    // store and return
    return $track[] = $num;
}
```

Keeping track of the generated randoms via static variable, which is only initiated once, will prevent generating the same number twice, but note that if you exceed the number of unique possibilities dictated by `$len` you will get stuck in an infinite loop. For example you can't call `random(1)` more than 9 times because `$len` is 1 and there are only 9 unique possibilities (excluding 0) so you need to have an idea about how many randoms you are going to need or choose big enough `$len` and not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function randomNumber($length)
    {
        $bytes = random_bytes($length / 2); 
         /* Generate random bytes (half the length because each byte is 
          represented by two hexadecimal characters) */
        $uniqueId = bin2hex($bytes);
   
       // Convert bytes to hexadecimal string
        return $uniqueId
 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if the environment is local there is no need to make a random number and mt_rand is like rand but four times faster

```
    protected function generateRandomNumber(int $length = 6)
    {
        $rand = '';
        $env = env('APP_ENV');
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $rand .= ($env == 'local') ? $i : mt_rand(($i == 1) ? 1 : 0, 9);
        }

        return (int) $rand;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here I need a random number of length 10,
Here is what I'm using:

`$characters = rand(1111111111, 9999999999);`